# How to add title in the description of my webSite in google

Tags: html, web

I want to know if someone have any idea to add the dot surrounded in red (attachement) on my website. I don't know how we call it.

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Just add sitemap to your site, either `xml` or `txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of the 'things' under the URL is a 'Sitelink' to a sub page of that website. There is more information [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that what i was looking for ;)

Comment: So glad I could help! If this answers your question could you mark is as answered? Thanks!

Comment: How can i do it ?

Comment: There should be a little check mark under my answers up and down arrows.

Comment: http://baselogic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/stackoverflow-green-check-mark.png

Comment: Thanks you, that helps me!